# Confused about local_time gem installation instructions ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

[image]

The instructions seem clear but I think they were written for an older version of rails.

Step 1 is clear enough. I added 'local_time' to my gemfile, ran a bundle install and restarted my server.

For step 2 I don't know what they are asking from me. To create a file called local-time.js in javascript/packs??

Then //= require local-time... That looks like something that would go in my manifest.js but that doesn't seem right.

So I put require("local-time"); in my application.js

However I am still getting no change. I do see this error in my source code.

**webpack_require**(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'local-time'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));

And this is what I have in my view.

```
<p><%= local_time_ago(message.created_at) %></p>
```

Please help!

Comment: Look at assets\config\manifest.js(or application.js). Try to add `//= require local-time` there

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue.
I had added the gem 'local_time' in my GemFile.
And had made a local-time.js file under app/javascript/local-time.js
Which is as follows:

```
//= require local-time
```

But it was not giving me any change.
So I installed the npm package. Using this line

```
npm i local-time
```

And after that I have included the below code in my application.js file

```
import LocalTime from "local-time"
LocalTime.start()
```

And this worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by new JS workflows in Rails with Webpacker. It seems the original instructions would work if you required local-time in the asset pipeline, but now you have to also install local-time with yarn. There's an open PR with the updated instructions

[PR to update instructions](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time/pull/104/files)

Hopefully it will get merged, but it's been several years.